# Rails system tests (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, system-testing

Currently changing my projects tests from rspec to built in system tests with rails 6 (also relatively new to rails) and getting this error when running 1 test.

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

I have no idea how to fix this/where to debug. The application is currently running through a docker container as well.

My current setup for the `application_system_test_case.rb` file is this:

```
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome
end
```